# Rmarkdown not rendering .Rmd to pdf, pandoc error 2

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown

I was trying to render an Rmarkdown file to pdf using the [beaverdown](https://github.com/zkamvar/beaverdown) package and got the following error:

> output file: thesis.knit.md
> --chapters has been removed. Use --top-level-division=chapter instead. Try pandoc.exe --help for more information. Error: pandoc document
> conversion failed with error 2 In addition: Warning message: In
> has_crop_tools() :  Tool(s) not installed or not in PATH: pdfcrop,
> ghostcript
> -> As a result, figure cropping will be disabled. Execution halted

I'm using:

- Pandoc 2.11.4
- MiKTeX 21.1

Session info:

```
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8.1 x64 (build 9600)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] pillar_1.4.7      compiler_4.0.3   
 [3] prettyunits_1.1.1 remotes_2.2.0    
 [5] tools_4.0.3       testthat_3.0.1   
 [7] digest_0.6.27     pkgbuild_1.2.0   
 [9] pkgload_1.1.0     gtable_0.3.0     
[11] tibble_3.0.6      evaluate_0.14    
[13] memoise_2.0.0     lifecycle_0.2.0  
[15] pkgconfig_2.0.3   rlang_0.4.10     
[17] DBI_1.1.0         cli_2.3.0        
[19] yaml_2.2.1        xfun_0.20        
[21] fastmap_1.1.0     withr_2.4.1      
[23] dplyr_1.0.4       knitr_1.31       
[25] generics_0.1.0    vctrs_0.3.6      
[27] desc_1.2.0        fs_1.5.0         
[29] devtools_2.3.2    grid_4.0.3       
[31] tidyselect_1.1.0  rprojroot_2.0.2  
[33] glue_1.4.2        R6_2.5.0         
[35] processx_3.4.5    rmarkdown_2.6.6  
[37] bookdown_0.21.6   sessioninfo_1.1.1
[39] ggplot2_3.3.3     blob_1.2.1       
[41] callr_3.5.1       purrr_0.3.4      
[43] magrittr_2.0.1    scales_1.1.1     
[45] ps_1.5.0          ellipsis_0.3.1   
[47] htmltools_0.5.1.1 usethis_2.0.0    
[49] assertthat_0.2.1  colorspace_2.0-0 
[51] tinytex_0.29      munsell_0.5.0    
[53] cachem_1.0.3      beaverdown_0.2.1 
[55] crayon_1.4.0
```

I haven't done anything besides rendering the template. Could this have anything to do with my current version of `pandoc`?

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check you path variable and look if you have right path to miktex and pandoc.

Comment: It does have to do with the pandoc version: looks like a package expects pandoc 1.x, which is ancient.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and thanks for your comments. I tried both suggestions and found that the package's pandoc version was indeed outdated. That's all I needed to know.